# Finding newest entry with data as a separate field

Tags: sql, date, max

I have joined 3 tables from 2 different databases and now I am looking to find the most recent cost of every MPN.  The cost field can exist multiple times on every MPN.  The significance is the "updated" date on the cost.  I either keep getting results that just return errors or I've written it to only return entries from the newest date instead of the newest date for all MPNs.  Can anyone assist?

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT cost.mpn, cost.total_cost, Products.mpn, inventory.status
FROM DatabaseA.dbo.cost
INNER JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.Products
ON cost.mpn = products.mpn
INNER JOIN DatabaseA.dbo.inventory
ON inventory.mpn = cost.mpn

SELECT max(cost.updated) FROM cost

WHERE inventory.status <> 'DISCONTINUED'
```

Thank you.

Comment: is this SQL SERVER, MySQL, No SQL ????

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  In particular, `row_number()` can be used to get what you want:

```
select cpi.*
from (SELECT c.mpn, c.total_cost, p.mpn, inventory.status,
             row_number() over (partition by c.mpn order by c.updateddate desc) as seqnum
      FROM DatabaseA.dbo.cost c INNER JOIN
           DatabaseB.dbo.Products p
           ON c.mpn = p.mpn INNER JOIN
           DatabaseA.dbo.inventory i
           ON i.mpn = c.mpn
     ) cpi
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Is it supported in MySQL or Access?

Comment: @M.Ali . . . No, but it is supported by most databases that use a three part naming convention with a default schema of `dbo`.  No accounting for databases that don't support standard functionality.